# arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ExecuteError

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, error-000840

This python code works in ArcGIS Pro but Not in ArcMap . I read some issues that mention a get around by making a feature layer. I tried that and I then get an error saying polytest doesn't exist. maybe since I am writing to a temp file?

```
    import arcpy, os, shutil, sys

# Path to store geoprocessing files
user_profile_path = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
gdb = r"{}/AppData/Local/Temp/PolyChecker/PolyCheck.gdb".format(user_profile_path)

# GDB already exists, delete it
if arcpy.Exists(gdb):
    shutil.rmtree(r"{}/AppData/Local/Temp/PolyChecker".format(user_profile_path))

# Create fresh GDB path
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(gdb))

# Create GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(os.path.dirname(gdb), os.path.basename(gdb))

# Script arguments
MapUnitPolys = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if MapUnitPolys == '#' or not MapUnitPolys:
    MapUnitPolys = "MapUnitPolys"  # provide a default value if unspecified

MapUnitPolys_CopyFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Set Geoprocessing environments
MapUnitPolys = MapUnitPolys

# Validate that all Polygons have a map unit

invalid_polygon_found = False

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(MapUnitPolys, ['SHAPE@', 'MapUnit', 'OBJECTID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #arcpy.AddMessage(str(row[1]))
        # Does this Polygon have a map unit
        if row[1] == "" or row[1] == "<Null>" or row[1] is None or row[1] is 0:
            invalid_polygon_found = True
            arcpy.AddMessage('Polygon OBJECT ID:{} is missing map unit... exiting.'.format(row[2]))


# Invalid polygons were found, terminate
if (invalid_polygon_found):
    sys.exit(1)

Polygon_Neighbors = "{}/polytest".format(gdb)

PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect = "{}/PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect".format(gdb)

inFeatures_lyr = "{}/inFeatures_1yr".format(gdb)

# Process: Polygon Neighbors
arcpy.PolygonNeighbors_analysis(MapUnitPolys, Polygon_Neighbors, "OBJECTID;MapUnit", "NO_AREA_OVERLAP", "BOTH_SIDES",
                                "", "METERS", "SQUARE_METERS")


# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Polygon_Neighbors, "NEW_SELECTION", "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")

# Process: Table Select
arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(Polygon_Neighbors, PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect, "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")

arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)

arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())

if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)[0]) > 0:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(MapUnitPolys, inFeatures_lyr)
else:
    print ("done")

# Process: Add Join
arcpy.AddJoin_management(inFeatures_lyr, "OBJECTID", PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect, "src_OBJECTID", "KEEP_COMMON")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeatures_lyr, MapUnitPolys_CopyFeatures, "", "0", "0", "0")

# Process: Remove Join
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(inFeatures_lyr, "")

# Execute Delete
arcpy.Delete_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)
arcpy.Delete_management(Polygon_Neighbors)

arcpy.AddMessage('All done! Check Polygons')
```

error1

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Downloads\GeMS-ArcPro-Toolbox-master\GeMS-ArcPro-Toolbox-master\Scripts\PolyChecker2.py", line 56, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Polygon_Neighbors, "NEW_SELECTION", "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7726, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
The value cannot be a table
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).


Failed to execute (PolyChecker).
Failed at Mon Aug 12 13:28:48 2019 (Elapsed Time: 3.90 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `Polygon_Neighbors` is a table. You'll need a [table view](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/tableview-class.htm) to perform your selection.

```
Polygon_Neighbors_tv = arcpy.MakeTableView_management (Polygon_Neighbors, "Polygon_Neighbors_tv") [0]
# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Polygon_Neighbors_tv, "NEW_SELECTION", "src_MapUnit = nbr_MapUnit")
```

Note that you can create a table view with with an sql query already assigned should you wish to skip the selection.